# Working with stored procedures (SQL Server) in WebAPI2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I don't know how to implement a stored procedure in my WebAPI controller in C#. I've created a simple stored procedure in my SQL Server database.

Here the example code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllGroups 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Id, name, code
    FROM dbo.Groups
END
GO
```

The stored procedure I've added in my Entity Framework Model. Now I want to use it in the WebAPI Controller, but I don't know how. I want to output all Groups.

Here is my WebAPI controller of Group:

```
public class QR_GroupController : ApiController
{
  private SampleContext db = new SampleContext();

  // GET: api/group
  public IQueryable<Group> GetAllGroups()
  {
     return db.Groups;
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:

My new Code:

```
public IQueryable<QR_Group> GetAllGroups()
{
   //The Stored procedure
   return db.GetAllGroups();
}
```

---

EDIT3:

That's the currently error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

How can I define a List in the stored procedure?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise, in your case, both `@name` as well as `@code` will be **truncated to 1 character length** - usually *not* what you want!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks marc I've seen it :) .. But the problem is still there..

Answer (score 2):

Error resolution is, you are not calling it as method. GetAllGroups should be called with () as follows

return db.GetAllGroups();

Comment: That's also the wrong answer. I had tried this and getting a new error: `No overload for 'GetAllGroups' matches 0 arguments.`

Comment: @yuro Did you supply `@Id, @name and @code` to the function?

Comment: you need to call the method with your input parameters. pass the parameters which you need. Also, you are not using any of input parameters, in stored procedure. Why to pass those parameters then.

Comment: @Eric I've tried the second answer but I've still the problem. Where I have to supply it?

Comment: @user3587767 How do I have to do?..I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @yuro  `return db.GetAllGroups(0, "", ""); // Put dummy parameter for all`

Comment: @Eric Ok, but I want to return the data from the database.

Comment: I think, I got your confusion. You dont' have to specify the columns of returned query. Currently, you have mentioned Id, name and code as input parameters to stored procedure. remove those and your SP would work fine.Change your SP to   
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllGroups 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Groups 
END 
GO

Comment: @user3587767 How can I define the query as a list? because the new error message tells: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TestApi.Group>'`

Comment: @user3587767 I've tried to SELECT the corresponding columns `SELECT Id, name, code FROM dbo.Groups` but it is the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure fixes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllGroups 
    @Id int,
    @name nvarchar(100),   --<-- define a length for param
    @code nvarchar(100)    --<-- define a length for param
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Groups
    WHERE Name = @Name   --<-- and finally actually use those params in your query
      AND Code = @Code 
      AND Id   = @Id 
END
GO
```

Comment: see my edited post. I've tried your solution but I have still a error message